# Integrating C programming in php

Tags: php, c, postgresql

Assume I have a simple C program as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float radius, area;
    printf("Radius = ?");  //change to read from database
    scanf("%f",&radius);
    area = 3.14159 * radius * radius;
    printf("Area = %f",area);
}
```

and then I have a web-based system which includes a postgresql data base and using php to retrieve my data. I would like to know is it possible for me to read the data in a table from the database (in this case is the radius) and pass through the c program and finally display the result on web page using php like echo 'area=...'

The problem I having right now is don't know how to read the data from the database and then pass through the c program and store in the database and then display it on the web page. Thank you in advance for every help.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way of solving your problem would be to write a PHP extension: that is, endowing your C code with a special interface which makes it callable directly by PHP code.

You may refer to the PHP manual: [PHP at the Core](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php).

Comment: However, if you don't want or cannot write a PHP extension, you could call the C code via the much less efficient `system()` interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)** to execute your C program and fetch the output

> shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output
> as a string